# Content inside div won't center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put content in the center of a div. I have set the content inside it as a `block` element and set it to `margin: 0 auto`; however the text is displayed normally - in the top left-hand corner.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3c6na6n4/2/

```
<div style="background: red; height: 300px; width: 300px;">
<div style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
<a style="width: 500px;" href="#>hhhhhhh</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the extra `div` and just set `text-align:center` on the outer one

```html
<div style="background: red; height: 300px; width: 300px;text-align:center;">
<a style="width: 500px;" href="#">hhhhhhh</a>
</div>
```

---

For the `margin:auto` trick to work the element needs to have a specific `width` defined.